# Analyzing ambient room volume

Tags: python, audio, volume

I am looking for a function/packages, which basically returns an integer which corresponds to the ambient volume in the room.

I thought that many people might have already wanted such a function, however, searing through the internet did not yield a result.
Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: "doesnt require and I/O"—Do you mean that this hypothetical operation should not require any input from, say, a microphone?

Comment: Im sorry, I should have specified. I dont want to record something, save it to disk and then reload it with python just to analyze it. This is what I meant with I/O.
The sound I want to record with a microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what I want:

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

CHUNK = 2 ** 11
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

while True:  # go for a few seconds
    data = np.frombuffer(stream.read(CHUNK), dtype=np.int16)
    peak = np.mean(np.abs(data))
    if peak > THRESHOLD:
        #do stuff
```